# How to check repetition of numbers in an array?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, random, nsmutablearray

I generate random numbers and store them in an array:

```
int RandomNumber = arc4random() % 12;
[NSMutablearray *Number addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:RandomNumber]];
```

Now I want to make sure the same number is not created randomly again.
Can any one please tell me how to do it with sample code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an `NSMutableSet` instead of an array while generating the numbers.
The following code will create an array of 10 unique random numbers:

```
NSMutableSet *aSet = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:10];
while([aSet count]<=10){
    int Randnum = arc4random() % 12;
    [aSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Randnum]];
} 
NSArray *arrayOfUniqueRandomNumbers = [aSet allObjects];
```